# Bring the attribute of an element to parent

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a question regarding bringing an attribute of an element to its parent or even grandparent. My XML file is as below :

```
     <Hierarchy>
    <Board>
        <Id>ABCDE</Id>
        <ParentId></ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>President</Name>
            <Description>Top level of the Hierarchy</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
            <LineManager>VP</LineManager>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Id>EFGHI</Id>
        <ParentId>ABCDE</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>VP</Name>
            <Description>Below the President</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
            <LineManager>Department_Heads</LineManager>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Id>JKLMN</Id>
        <ParentId>EFGHI</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
            <Description>Reports to the VP</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
            <LineManager>Supervisors</LineManager>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Id>OPQRS</Id>
        <ParentId>JKLMN</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Supervisors</Name>
            <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL4</Template>
            <LineManager>Employees</LineManager>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Id>TUVWX</Id>
        <ParentId>OPQRS</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Employees</Name>
            <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL5</Template>
            <LineManager></LineManager>
        </General>
    </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

How do I bring the "LineManager" from all levels directly at "VP". So I need to skip the "Supervisor" and "Department_Heads", directly pick the "LineManager" from all level in the hierarchy  and place it at VP as an  element. The expected output is below :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
   <Board>
      <Name>President</Name>
      <Description>Top level of the Hierarchy</Description>
      <LineManager>VP</LineManager>
      <Board>
         <Name>VP</Name>
         <Description>Below the President</Description>
         <LineManager>Department_Heads</LineManager>
         <LineManager>Supervisors</LineManager>
         <LineManager>Employees</LineManager>
      </Board>
   </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

So here, all the "LineManager" element from all levels below VP is placed at VP.

I tried something and I will post it below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Hierarchy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Hierarchy/Board">
                <xsl:if test="General/Template='LEVEL1'">
                    <xsl:variable name="level1" select="Id"/>
                    <Board>
                       <Name><xsl:value-of select = "General/Name"/></Name>
                        <Description><xsl:value-of select = "General/Description"/></Description>
                        <LineManager><xsl:value-of select = "General/LineManager"/></LineManager>
                        
                        <xsl:for-each select="//Board">
                            <xsl:if test="ParentId = $level1">
                               
                                <xsl:if test="General/Template='LEVEL2'">
                                <xsl:variable name="level2" select="Id"/>
                                    <Board>
                                        <Name><xsl:value-of select = "General/Name"/></Name>
                                         <Description><xsl:value-of select = "General/Description"/></Description>
                                         <LineManager><xsl:value-of select = "General/LineManager"/></LineManager>
                                         
                                       
                                        <xsl:for-each select="//Board">
                                            <xsl:if test="ParentId = $level2">
                                                <xsl:variable name="tagname1" select="General/LineManager"/>
                                                <xsl:for-each select="General">
                                                    <xsl:if test="LineManager='Supervisors'">
                                                       
                                                            <LineManager><xsl:value-of select="$tagname1"/></LineManager>
                                                           
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </Board>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Board>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Hierarchy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of my test gives me only the element directly under VP which is the "Department_Heads". But I want all the "LineManager" elements from all levels to be placed at VP.

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: The instruction `<xsl:copy-of select="descendant::Attribute"/>` will copy all descendant **elements** named `Attribute` to the current node. Please note that the term *attribute* has another meaning in XML.

Comment: can you please write an example. Also <Attribute> is not an element itself, but an attribute of "Employees".

Comment: I cannot  because I do not understand your stylesheet. If you reduce your code to a [mcve], then I may be able to. And no, `Attribute`is NOT an attribute of Employees. It is an element, a child of the `General` element. You are dealing with a highly technical issue here; it is important to use the correct terminology: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-logical-struct

Comment: I have made my code simple and it works properly now. I have also edited my question and made it simpler. Please have a look.